# Group by stats in Solr using Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, statistics, sunspot-solr

I have stats for some particular query that is calculating sum of prices for the entire set of results. I would like to have different stat for different group inside returned results.

For example, sum of prices for results with status = 'In progress' separated from sum of prices for results with status = 'Complete'.

Is something like this possible using sunspot?

Existing query:

```
 Residential.search do
     with(:zip_code, <zip_code>)

     stat(:list_price, :type => "min")
     stat(:list_price, :type => "max")
     stat(:list_price, :type => "mean")
     stat(:square_feet, :type => "min")
     stat(:square_feet, :type => "max")
     stat(:square_feet, :type => "mean")
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the solr Stats Component page

```
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent
```

There you can see the stat component has a possibility to generate a stat for facet field.

This means you can generate a solr query like

```
q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=list_price&stats.field=square_feet&stats.facet=status
```

This will return the global stat and a stat for each status for the fields list_price and square_feet

The resultset will look like the following:

I am assuming you are using the sunspot stats library https://github.com/giovannelli/sunspot_stats

And there they say that the param after your_field is the facet field

```
stat(:your_field, :facet => :your_facet_filed, :type => "min")
```

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thank you for the descriptive answer!